# How can I get my HP 15-ab143cl laptop to boot from USB?

Tags: boot, usb

Wanting to dump Win10 for 16.04LTS. I've tried literally dozens of workarounds, and feeling that HP just won't allow a USB boot to Linux. Legacy on, correct boot order, secure boot disabled, etc. I've made the stick using three different apps, the most recent being Rufus w/both UEFI and BIOS MBR setting. I know the stick works. This is nutz.

Comment: You need to read and understand this first: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Don't dump W10. Keep it around to perform tasks that can only be performed in Windows... like BIOS updates, etc. Configure your setup as a dual boot. Do you have access to a DVD/burner on this machine? My experience is that you'll have better luck burning a DVD and booting that for your install. Be sure to MD5SUM the .iso file to make sure that you got a good download.

Comment: I've done this conversion a dozen times on other machines. It's not my machine, but a colleague's. We have no interest in retaining W10 for any reason. Anyway...thanks to MichaelBay for the link; it's a much better explanation than I'd found so far, but still nothing works. I've read dozens of posts from folks with similar issues on this line of machine. I'm going to go into town Monday, buy some blank DVDs, and burn a boot disk. Maybe that will get through it. Thanks also for the prompt responses. I've used Ubuntu for several years, and run into this once before. I'll advise what happens.

Comment: FWIW...it gets to grub, but then no matter what you select you get a blank screen and lockup...no matter how it's configured. Argh.

Comment: Dunno if anyone's interested, but here's a follow-up. I got another machine to burn a boot DVD; then brought it back here, and found the same behavior on boot...looked just like when I tried to boot it from USB. Next step...update ALL the firmware on the laptop, including the DVD drive, and see wha' hoppen. Also will try the boot DVD on the same desktop I used to burn it, and see if it works correctly.

Comment: Last one...and I never thought in a google of years that I'd say this...but I'm rather convinced that this particular model of laptop simply will not run 16.04LTS at all. Grub boots, but the OS will not proceed. All manner of fixes (including boot-repair) and such have been tried multiple times w/multiple settings. In 57 years of IT at all levels, I've never said...I GIVE UP. Two identical machines act identically. BTW...they also won't burn a CD...period. Oy. Thank you all for reading, responding, and giving valuable and appreciated info and suggestions.

Comment: You say that the Grub menu appears on the screen but when you select any of the menu entries it won't boot Ubuntu, right? What do you see on the screen after you try to boot Ubuntu? Is it black or purple or something else? Is there any text written? Is the image all garbled and filled with weird patterns? In that case you may want to have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it.

Comment: Thank you, David...that's new information, and I did not know about the nomodeset, etc. options. I will try that before giving up.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to David Foerster for his pointing me to the `nomodeset` trigger. Dozens of inquiries, and I saw nothing on that until he posted. It worked. It's now obviously an issue as to the machines' Nvidia/AMD setup and should be cured with driver updates. Very grateful for the help.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/749089)

Comment: @Stormvirux this is the only answer. Elaine Albertson is thanking a commenter and this answer is useful because it says what solved the problem and there aren't any other answers